# How to implement Swipe in Android on only a section of the Screen?

Tags: android

I've been trying to implement Swipe gestures on only a section of the screen, on Android. I can manage detecting a swipe anywhere on the screen, but I can't seem to put a check to ensure that a upward/downward swipe only takes place in, say, the first 200 pixels from the left. 
Here's the sections of the code that I wish to implement the Swipe gestures in (Since the swipe wasn't working, I've currently implemented arrowheads for the movement, those need to be replace by code to detect swipe for only that section of the screen).

```
import java.util.List;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;

import com.osahub.framework.Game;
import com.osahub.framework.Graphics;
import com.osahub.framework.Input.TouchEvent;
import com.osahub.framework.Screen;

public class LevelDetailsScreen extends Screen {

    public Buttons buttons[] = new Buttons[Assets.NUMBER_OF_LEVELS + 1];
    public static int counter = 1;
    public static boolean isUpEnabled = false, isDownEnabled = true;
    public int displayInfoLevelNumber = 0;

    public LevelDetailsScreen(Game game) {
        super(game);
        for (int i = 1; i <= Assets.NUMBER_OF_LEVELS; i++) {
            buttons[i] = new Buttons(10, (60 + 75 * (i - 1)));
        }
    }

    public class Buttons {
        int centerX, centerY, speedY;
        boolean movingDown = false, movingUp = false;
        public int levelNumber = counter++;

        Buttons(int centerX, int centerY) {
            setCenterX(centerX);
            setCenterY(centerY);
        }

        public void moveUp() {
            speedY = -5;
        }

        public void moveDown() {
            speedY = 5;
        }

        public void stopUp() {
            setMovingUp(false);
            stop();
        }

        public void stopDown() {
            setMovingDown(false);
            stop();
        }

        public void stop() {
            if (isMovingDown() == false && isMovingUp() == false) {
                speedY = 0;
            }

            if (isMovingDown() == false && isMovingUp() == true) {
                moveDown();
            }

            if (isMovingDown() == true && isMovingUp() == false) {
                moveUp();
            }
        }

        public void update() {
            centerY += speedY;
        }

        public void isValidMove() {
            if (centerY >= 60 + 75 * (levelNumber - 1)) {
                isUpEnabled = false;
                stopUp();
            } else {
                isUpEnabled = true;
            }
            if (centerY <= 360 + 75 * (levelNumber - 10)) {
                isDownEnabled = false;
                stopDown();
            } else {
                isDownEnabled = true;
            }
        }

        public int getCenterX() {
            return centerX;
        }

        public void setCenterX(int centerX) {
            this.centerX = centerX;
        }

        public int getCenterY() {
            return centerY;
        }

        public void setCenterY(int centerY) {
            this.centerY = centerY;
        }

        public int getSpeedY() {
            return speedY;
        }

        public void setSpeedY(int speedY) {
            this.speedY = speedY;
        }

        public boolean isMovingUp() {
            return movingUp;
        }

        public void setMovingUp(boolean movingUp) {
            this.movingUp = movingUp;
        }

        public boolean isMovingDown() {
            return movingDown;
        }

        public void setMovingDown(boolean movingDown) {
            this.movingDown = movingDown;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void update(float deltaTime) {

        for (int i = 1; i < MainMenuScreen.levels.length; i++) {
            MainMenuScreen.levels[i] = game.retrieveLevelsData(i);
        }

        List<TouchEvent> touchEvents = game.getInput().getTouchEvents();

            // Swipe Needs to be implemented here, instead of the touch events.
        int len = touchEvents.size();
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            TouchEvent event = touchEvents.get(i);
            if (event.type == TouchEvent.TOUCH_DOWN) {
                if (inBounds(event, 60, 8, 43, 39)) {
                    for (int j = 1; j < buttons.length; j++) {
                        buttons[j].moveUp();
                        buttons[j].setMovingUp(true);
                    }
                }
                if (inBounds(event, 60, 433, 43, 39)) {
                    for (int j = 1; j < buttons.length; j++) {
                        buttons[j].moveDown();
                        buttons[j].setMovingDown(true);
                    }
                }
                for (int j = 1; j < buttons.length; j++) {
                    if (inBounds(event, buttons[j].centerX, buttons[j].centerY, buttons[j].centerX + 151,
                            buttons[j].centerY + 60)) {
                        displayInfoLevelNumber = buttons[j].levelNumber;
                    }
                }
            }

            if (event.type == TouchEvent.TOUCH_UP) {
                if (inBounds(event, 60, 8, 43, 39)) {
                    for (int j = 1; j < buttons.length; j++) {
                        buttons[j].stopUp();
                    }
                }
                if (inBounds(event, 60, 433, 43, 39)) {
                    for (int j = 1; j < buttons.length; j++) {
                        buttons[j].stopDown();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        for (int j = 1; j < buttons.length; j++) {
            buttons[j].update();
            buttons[j].isValidMove();
        }
    }

    private boolean inBounds(TouchEvent event, int x, int y, int width, int height) {
        if (event.x > x && event.x < x + width - 1 && event.y > y && event.y < y + height - 1)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(float deltaTime) {
        // drawing things on screen
}

    @Override
    public void pause() {
    }

    @Override
    public void resume() {

    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {

    }

    @Override
    public void backButton() {
        counter = 1;
        game.setScreen(new LevelSelectionScreen(game));
    }
    }
```

The extended file Screen is an interface which further calls a class AndroidGame. The AndroidGame is as follows:

```
package com.osahub.framework.implementation;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedIns

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Bitmap.Config;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.PowerManager;
import android.os.PowerManager.WakeLock;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;

import com.osahub.framework.Audio;
import com.osahub.framework.FileIO;
import com.osahub.framework.Game;
import com.osahub.framework.Graphics;
import com.osahub.framework.Input;
import com.osahub.framework.Screen;
import com.osahub.robotgame.Assets;
import com.osahub.robotgame.Level;
import com.osahub.robotgame.MainMenuScreen;

public abstract class AndroidGame extends Activity implements Game {
    AndroidFastRenderView renderView;
    Graphics graphics;
    Audio audio;
    Input input;
    FileIO fileIO;
    Screen screen;
    WakeLock wakeLock;

@OverridetanceState);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    boolean isPortrait = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT;
    int frameBufferWidth = isPortrait ? 480 : 800;
    int frameBufferHeight = isPortrait ? 800 : 480;
    Bitmap frameBuffer = Bitmap.createBitmap(frameBufferWidth, frameBufferHeight, Config.RGB_565);

    float scaleX = (float) frameBufferWidth / getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
    float scaleY = (float) frameBufferHeight / getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();

    renderView = new AndroidFastRenderView(this, frameBuffer);
    graphics = new AndroidGraphics(getAssets(), frameBuffer);
    fileIO = new AndroidFileIO(this);
    audio = new AndroidAudio(this);
    input = new AndroidInput(this, renderView, scaleX, scaleY);
    screen = getInitScreen();
    setContentView(renderView);

    PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    wakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK, "MyGame");

}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    wakeLock.acquire();
    screen.resume();
    renderView.resume();
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    wakeLock.release();
    renderView.pause();
    screen.pause();

    if (isFinishing())
        screen.dispose();
}

@Override
public Input getInput() {
    return input;
}

@Override
public FileIO getFileIO() {
    return fileIO;
}

@Override
public Graphics getGraphics() {
    return graphics;
}

@Override
public Audio getAudio() {
    return audio;
}

@Override
public void setScreen(Screen screen) {
    if (screen == null)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Screen must not be null");

    this.screen.pause();
    this.screen.dispose();
    screen.resume();
    screen.update(0);
    this.screen = screen;
}

public Screen getCurrentScreen() {
    return screen;
}
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks a lot..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set transperent sprites or images in the area where you want to get the touchlistners and listen for there touch by
image.setonTouchListner()

Hope this helps